# How can I programmatically obtain the company info used to digitally sign an assembly in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, code-signing, digital-signature

As a means of simple security, I was previously checking the digital signature of a downloaded update package for my program against its public key to ensure that it originated from me. However, as I'm using cheap code signing certs (Tucows), I am unable to renew an existing cert and therefore the keys change every time I need to renew.

Therefore, a more reliable means would be to verify the organization information embedded in the signed assembly (which is displayed in the UAC dialog) against my well-known organization string, as this will continue to be the same.

Does anyone know how to obtain this information from a digitally-signed assembly?

Comment: Crap I just realized I'm signing an xml document, not the actual assembly, which doesn't embed company info at all. Guess this won't help me after all! :(

Comment: If you sign XML data properly and the certificate is included (or referenced), you still have a certificate which can be expected (and we have XMLBlackbox for this too :).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it enough to just check that the assembly is strong named using your key?  Authenticode mostly benefits the end user who can identify that you are who you say you are (due to the efforts of the cert. authority).  To my mind, in your situation, there's no extra security in an authenticode certificate over a simple strong name.

I assume a strong name is much simpler to verify, and you won't have to worry about your key changing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the assembly is signed using Authenticode technology and X.509 certificates (and not just strong-named), you need an Authenticode reader code (or component) to extract the certificate and validate it. After that you will find organization name in one of the fields of certificate's SubjectName or SubjectRDN record.

We offer [Authenticode reader class and certificate manipulation class](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pki.php) in PKIBlackbox package.